# Class Extends Fatal error: Class 'DatabaseObject' not found

Tags: php, inheritance

I've been following a **PHP OOP** course of LinkedIn. When I arrive to "Inheritance" part, the code in my PC fails and I cannot fix it.

The code has an **auto load** in the very first file.

This is when the project fails. It Never failed before, but when I arrive to inheritance, it fails.

> Example: Class B extends A. **This fails**.

I've tried the following:

1. Add `__DIR__` to the autoload. Some warnings disappear, but the error still alive.
2. Change php tag `<?php` to short version `<?`
3. Change permissions to 777 (755 by default).

I expect to load the view called bicycles.php. A table with all the bicycles. This view works always, but in the moment I use inheritance, it fails.

---

### **initialize.php**

```
<?php
    foreach(glob('/classes/*.class.php') as $file) {
    require_once($file);
  }

  // Autoload class definitions
  function my_autoload($class) {
    if(preg_match('/\A\w+\Z/', $class)) {
      include('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
    }
  }
  spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');

  $database = db_connect();
  DatabaseObject::set_database($database);
?>
```

---

### Parent Class: DatabaseObject

```
<?php
    class DatabaseObject {

          static protected $database;
          static protected $table_name = "";
          static protected $columns = [];
          public $errors = [];
  }
?>
```

---

### Child Class: Bicycle

```
<?php


class Bicycle extends DatabaseObject {

  static protected $table_name = 'bicycles';
  static protected $db_columns = ['id', 'brand', 'model', 'year', 'category', 'color', 'gender', 'price', 'weight_kg', 'condition_id', 'description'];

  public $id;
  public $brand;
  public $model;
  public $year;
  public $category;
  public $color;
  public $description;
  public $gender;
  public $price;
  public $weight_kg;
  public $condition_id;

  public const CATEGORIES = ['Road', 'Mountain', 'Hybrid', 'Cruiser', 'City', 'BMX'];

  public const GENDERS = ['Mens', 'Womens', 'Unisex'];

  public const CONDITION_OPTIONS = [
    1 => 'Beat up',
    2 => 'Decent',
    3 => 'Good',
    4 => 'Great',
    5 => 'Like New'
  ];

  public function __construct($args=[]) {
    //$this->brand = isset($args['brand']) ? $args['brand'] : '';
    $this->brand = $args['brand'] ?? '';
    $this->model = $args['model'] ?? '';
    $this->year = $args['year'] ?? '';
    $this->category = $args['category'] ?? '';
    $this->color = $args['color'] ?? '';
    $this->description = $args['description'] ?? '';
    $this->gender = $args['gender'] ?? '';
    $this->price = $args['price'] ?? 0;
    $this->weight_kg = $args['weight_kg'] ?? 0.0;
    $this->condition_id = $args['condition_id'] ?? 3;

    // Caution: allows private/protected properties to be set
    // foreach($args as $k => $v) {
    //   if(property_exists($this, $k)) {
    //     $this->$k = $v;
    //   }
    // }
  }
?>
```

---

### Errors and Warnings

Warning: include(classes/DatabaseObject.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/................/chain_gang/private/initialize.php on line 45

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'classes/DatabaseObject.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/............/chain_gang/private/initialize.php on line 45

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DatabaseObject' not found in /home/............../chain_gang/private/initialize.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /home/................/chain_gang/public/staff/bicycles/index.php(1): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/................./chain_gang/private/initialize.php on line 51

---

Project directory:

[image]

**PS:** *The codes examples are not complete at all. Only the most important part I think.*

Comment: First of all why you need autoloading if you required all classes using glob? Use only one of those. Secondly, the glob Is not gonna work since you glob /classes in the root of your FS which Is probably not where they Are. Third, your autoload function Is refering the classes dir relative to Its own location which might not be where they Are. 4 you should delimit the regex with symbol for line start `^` And line end `$`. 5 databaseobject class Is missing closing bracket. 6 use of closing PHP tag `?>` Is discouraged. It could help if you provide your directory structure.

Comment: This code it's from a Linkedin PHP OOP tutorial. I don't know why are existing two options (glob and autoload).

The classes are all in 'classes' folder. I uploaded an image.

Comment: Ah then i Guess Its problem of the case. Your files Are in lower case. But classes have uppercase letters

Comment: Btw avoid using redundant `.class` suffix. Being in classes directory Is far enough...

Comment: You're totally right. The files are all in lowercase. I change them all to CamelCase and now seems it works perfectly. I don't understand why people use lowercase for classes. Isn't always good practice to use CamelCase for the Classes?

Comment: Well there Is no rule for that but in practice yes, most of the code out there names classes in CamelCase, And for the sake of consistency Its good to do it too. Anyway i had no idea LinkedIn has any turorials, but if your code comes from the tutorial i must say the tutorial Is quite crappy And you might do good if you look around the web for a better one And let LinkedIn Focus on providing job opportunities...

Comment: Anyway I will finish up that tutorial, because I think it's pretty good enough to learn some basics I need. Thanks for your help guys, specially to you, Slepic. Always there is something to learn, even it's a little detail like this.

Comment: Sure no problem. I understand you wanna Finish it when you got this far. Just remember to be critical And think for yourself as the tutorial might suggest things that Are not the best way to go...

Answer (score 1):

There is a } missing after the declaration of the DatabaseObject class

Note that your autoloader is not usefull because you do a require_once of all the classes in the /classes directory ;)

Comment: The glob Is not working because the Path given Is absolute, i doubt He really has classes folders in the root.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, adding strtoupper after glob.

```
// Load class definitions manually
// -> Individually
// require_once('classes/song.class.php');
// -> All classes in directory
foreach (glob (strtoupper('Controller/*.Controller.php')) as $file) {
    require_once($file);
}
```

So the error message disappeared.